# meaning of knowing

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **knowing** in the following sentence

> Having received such a stinging rebuke by the Supreme Court, the right course of action for Mr. Oli should be to resign on moral grounds, but **knowing** the combative politician, that is not going to happen.

[To Read The Full Article](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/judicial-blow-the-hindu-editorial-on-nepal-supreme-court-reinstating-parliament/article33935647.ece?homepage=true)

Comment: ...but given our knowledge of the... or ...but because we know what he is like, that is... is the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some examples will help:

- Knowing that fire is hot, I don't touch it.
- Knowing that he's a trustworthy person, I gave him the keys to my car.
- Knowing that he's a vegetarian, I made him tofu.
- Knowing English, I could understand this answer.

Mathematically, it's p -> q.  Knowing something (p), I did something else (q).

Comment: It's worth stating that participle phrases like those above aren't limited to first person **I**, as all of your examples seem to indicate: they work with any case. For example: "Knowing, her, ***he** shouldn't have expected her to arrive on time".  "Knowing this politician, **we** don't put much faith in his promises".